# Model binding Asp net core 2.2

Tags: model-binding, asp.net-core-2.2

I have the following complex model:

```
public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public int UserId { get; set; }
    }
```

I need to bind the whole model in my action method using `[FromBody]`, while `Id` property should come `[FromQuery]`. My action method looks like this:

```
public IActionResult Delete([FromBody]User userRequest)
{
    // Some code
}
```

The thing is that I can't change the model, because it is 3-rd party and also, I can't have `Id` as the second parameter in action method, because I have validation logic for `userRequest` where I need the `Id`. Any ideas?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use a DTO/view model and map over to `User`. For example:

```
public class UserDTO
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
public IActionResult Delete(int id, [FromBody]UserDTO userRequest)
{
    var user = new User
    {
        Id = id,
        UserName = userRequest.UserName,
        UserId = userRequest.UserId
    }

    // do something
}
```

Comment: Please, read question carefully. `I can't have Id as the second parameter in action method bla-bla-bla...`. This way is obvious, but doesn't feet my needs.

Comment: I need to bake a cake but I can't use flour. This is what's required. Perhaps if you provided more information about what you're actually trying to achieve there might be a better way, but as it stands, this is your answer.

Comment: I need all of `User` properties be available when I do the model validation. I'm using FluentValidation for that purpose. That is the reason why the answer isn't good for me. Because in this case I need to inject corresponding validator to my controller and do validation manually, which pollutes code. I'm looking for some clean solution

Comment: But, your id is not something that should be posted in the first place, let alone need to be validated. The whole point of having it be part of the URI is to uniquely identify a particular resource. The post, then, should only ever modify that particular resource, so allowing an id to be posted only opens up an attack vector.

Comment: Any validation logic should be on your DTO, fluent or otherwise. Your entity should only have stuff relevant to the database, since that's what it serves. Long and short, good app design negates your issues.

Comment: Sir, your words are perfectly reasonable, but this isn't what I've asked about. My question is more about binding under certain circumstances, than about design and REST.

Comment: You're missing the point. If you want the id from the URL, *you need an id param*. You're saying you can't do that for this reason or that, and I'm telling you that if you simply design your app properly, that won't be an issue. Regardless, this is your answer. Again, how can I bake a cake without flour: you can't. Do it right.

Comment: I can create custom `formatter`, where I can get id from route and assign in to my `[FromBody]` model. I don't say it is right way to do, but it is still possible, even without flour :-)

Comment: I've marked you answer as accepted, as it makes more sense than anything else. Thank you, sir!